# ¿Porqué me sale error csrf verification failed?

Tags: django

Esta es mi vista:

```
def validarcelda(request):
    error = ''
    success = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        celda = request.POST.get('celda', None)
        if not celda:
            error = _('Ingrese numero de celda')
        elif Empaque.objects.filter(celda__exact=celda.exists()):
            error = _('La celda ya existe')
        else:
            success = True
    ajax_vars = {'success': success, 'error': error}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ajax_vars),content_type='application/javascript')
```

Esta es mi plantilla:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="reset" data-dismiss="modal" class="cerrarmodal">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> </i>
    </button>
    <h4> <span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Ingresar caja</h4>
</div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form class="formatolinea" name="empaque" id="empaque" action="{% url 'empaqueingreso' %}" onSubmit="return iempaque();">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <label>Variedad</label>
                        <select name="variedad" value="{{variedad}}">
                            <option>Seleccione la varieda</option>
                            <option>Freedom</option>
                            <option>Vendela</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="mensaje" id="mensajev" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar la variedad</div>
                        <label>Grado</label>
                        <select name="grado" value='{{grado}}'>
                            <option>Seleccione el grado</option>
                            <option value="40">40</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                            <option value="60">60</option>
                            <option value="70">70</option>
                        </select>
                        <div name="mensajeg" class="mensaje" id="mensajeg" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar el grado</div>
                        <label>Tipo de empaque</label>
                        <select name="empaque" value='{{empaque}}'>
                            <option>Seleccione el empaque</option>
                            <option>Tabaco</option>
                            <option>Full</option>
                            <option>Cuarto</option>
                            <option>Tercio</option>
                            <option>Octavos</option>
                        </select>
                        <div name="mensajee" class="mensaje" id="mensajee" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar el empaque</div>
                        <label>Cantidad de ramos</label>
                        <input type="number" name="ramos" value="{{ramos}}" placeholder="Digite los ramos">
                        <div name="mensajer" class="mensaje" id="mensajer" style='display: none;'>Debe digitar el numero de ramos</div>
                        <label>Unidades por ramo</label>
                         <select name="unidades" onChange="otro(this.value);">
                            <option>Unidades por ramo</option>
                            <option>20</option>
                            <option>25</option>
                            <option value="Otro" id="otro">Otro</option>
                        </select>
                        <div name="mensajeu" class="mensaje" id="mensajeu" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar las unidades por ramo</div>
                        <label id="digite" style=' display: none; '>Digite la cantidad</label>
                        <input type="number" name="tabaco" id="unidad" style=' display: none; ' onChange="cambiar(this.value);">
                        <label>Comercializadora</label>
                        <select name="comercializadora" value="{{comercializadora}}">
                            <option>Seleccione la comercializadora</option>
                            <option>QU</option>
                            <option>GO</option>
                            <option>FX</option>
                            <option>BG</option>
                        </select>
                        <div name="mensajec" class="mensaje" id="mensajec" style='display: none;'>Debe seleccionar la comercializadora</div>
                        <label>Numero de celda</label>
                        <input type="number" name="celda" id="celda">
                        <div name="mensajecd" class="mensaje" id="mensajecd" style='display: none;'>Debe digitar el numero de celda</div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "{% url 'validarcelda' %}",
                            data: {'celda': $('#celda').val(), 
                                   'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
                            dataType: "text",
                            success: function(response) {
                                var response = $.parseJSON(response);
                                if (response.success){
                                    return true;
                                }else{
                                    alert(response.error);
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            error: function(rs, e) {
                                alert(rs.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                        </script>
                        <button class="guardar" type="submit" onclick="iempaque()"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button>
                        <button class="cancelar" type="reset" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.containerfluid -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: puedes poner el codiogo del  la función iempaque() ? estás incluyendo ahí el csrf_token?

Answer (score 1):

Qué middleware clases tienes en las settings.py?

Además creo que esto no se hace así:

```
'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax

Prueba como dice en la doc:

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
```

Con eso de arriba estas poniendo el input en el json, porque {{ csrf_token }} te genera un input hidden con el token

intenta con eso:

```
'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

El error csrf verification failed se te está originando debido a que el servidor no esta reconociendo en el cuerpo de tu solicitud el token csrf que permita validar el request que se esta ejecutando.

El detalle en tu planteamiento radica en la forma en la que estás ejecutando tu petición AJAX, ya que no se esta añadiendo el token csrf a la petición y por ende, el servidor esta respondiendo con este error.

Una de las formas de hacerlo es realizando una función que te permita añadir el token al encabezado de tu petición.

Te recomiendo que sigas los pasos suministrados en este [post](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/), que es de gran ayuda al empezar a realizar la integración AJAX-Django.

La otra opción es utilizar el método `serialize` de `jquery` para serializar toda la data del formulario *(y no uno por uno, y muchos menos como estás queriendo enviar el token en tu versión actual del código)*, quedando tu porción de código de esta a manera:

`data: $("#YOUR-FORM-ID").serialize(),`.